# How do I get my-own-website-urls that ads refer to from the facebook marketing API in the facebook graph API explorer?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

**What I have:**

When I paste *this* code

```
act_**censored**/insights/?&level=ad
```

...in *this* field in the API-Explorer
[image]

...I get a json file with *this* information:

```
  {
      "date_start": "2018-07-08",
      "date_stop": "2018-08-06",
      "impressions": "**censored**",
      "spend": "**censored**",
      "account_id": "**censored**",
      "campaign_id": "**censored**",
      "adset_id": "**censored**",
      "ad_id": "**censored**"
    }
```

By the way: I have `read_insights` permission.

**What I need:**

Rather than just getting the ad_id, I also want to get the according url on my website, which the ad refers to.

**Question:**

What do I need to change the code in the first line to, in order to fulfill this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to place_page_id, Please check the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns#actionsbreakdown

Comment: Thanks. But I don't manage to translate this in to code. act_**censored**/insights/?&level=ad&fields=place_page_id does not work in my case. What am I doing wrong?